# How to 'embed' SBT plugin in my Scala project

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

Im currently using an SBT plugin that runs as part of the `compile` task but wish to amend it. Have contacted author but no responses.

Can anyone give me a high-level overview of steps to import the functionality into my project so I can customise it? Its a single Object.

- If the object is 'hooking' into `compile` task then I assume it should still extend `plugin`?
- Currently, I have a compile error on `import sbt.Keys._`

`import sbt._` works

`import sbt.Keys._` object Keys is not a member of package set.

Do I need SBT jar as an unmanaged dependency of my project?

build.properties contains `sbt.version=0.13.5`

BTW - I shall be keeping original authors details in the code to attribute the code to them.

---

Edit.

I am using [sbt-cxf-wsdl2java](https://github.com/ebiznext/sbt-cxf-wsdl2java) plugin.

I mainly wish to upgrade the version of CXF being used by the plugin, since this is hardcoded not the plugin object code.

I could fork it, change code, create new plugin and push to a repo to then declare in my project but this seems a lot of effort for a relatively small change - hence my wish to 'embed' the plugin code in my application.

I guess I need to read the docs and figure out how plugins work in order to understand this - but if anyone can give me a few pointers to save me time then I would really appreciate it.

build.sbt (with the relevant plugin bits):

```
lazy val wsPackage = "com.myCompany"

seq(cxf.settings :_*)

cxf.wsdls := Seq(
    cxf.Wsdl((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "My.wsdl", Seq("-p",  wsPackage), "modelOutputDir")
)
```

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.ebiznext.sbt.plugins" % "sbt-cxf-wsdl2java" % "0.1.4")
```

Comment: Could you show your full build.sbt file?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html ? It describes how to write a simple plugin. BTW, latest sbt version is 0.13.8, although I think it shouldn't matter for writing a plugin.

Comment: @JamieP Can you share what SBT plugin you speak of? Might help answering the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I have edit my post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `build.sbt`, you can override configuration keys (which are located in `com.ebiznext.sbt.plugins.CxfWsdl2JavaPlugin.Keys`). For example:

```
lazy val wsPackage = "com.myCompany"

Seq(cxf.settings :_*)

cxf.cxfVersion := "3.1.2" // override CXF version

cxf.wsdls := Seq(
  cxf.Wsdl((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "My.wsdl", Seq("-p",  wsPackage, "-impl", "-mark-generated"), "unique wsdl id")
)
```